# Reverse engineering with custom ReverseEgineeringStrategy

Tags: maven, reverse-engineering, hibernate-tools

I want to do reverse engineering (generate java classes from my database) with a custom `ReverseEgineeringStrategy`. I succeeded to do this using `hibernate-tools` plugin for eclipse. 
But I want to use `hibernate3-maven-plugin` to do this. I searched a lot for an example but neither of the examples I found worked for me.

If anyone know how we can do this, I appreciate his help.

Comment: I had checked this a long while ago and at the time, there was just an Ant way of doing it. If you like, you can invoke it using the `antrun-maven-plugin`.

Comment: I don't know if my answer is what are you talking about?

Comment: Check this out: https://jonamlabs.com/how-to-use-hibernate-tools-maven-plugin-to-generate-jpa-entities-from-an-existing-database/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried `hibernate3-maven-plugin` version 3.0

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
```

Unfortunately I had errors and I didn't succeeded to make it work (messages of exceptions didn't help me a lot neither).

So I tried the version 2.2 and it works perfectly, here my `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>hbm2java</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hbm2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <components>
                            <component>
                                <name>hbm2java</name>
                                <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
                                <outputDirectory>target/generatedClasses</outputDirectory>
                            </component>
                        </components>
                        <componentProperties>
                            <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                            <ejb3>false</ejb3>
                            <revengfile>${basedir}\hibernate.reveng.xml</revengfile>
                            <reversestrategy>com.it.mybatis.MyReverseEngineeringStrategy</reversestrategy>
                            <propertyfile>${basedir}\database.properties</propertyfile>
                        </componentProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                    <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1_3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-CR1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question, or an update with more information? If it's an update, please delete it and move the actual text to the original question.

Comment: It is an answer, sorry forget to mention that it works.